# How do I make this Javascript checkbox trigger action work like my CSS only example

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

I'm using the following code to test for "if" a checkbox is checked on page load.
If it is, then a certain additional field will be shown (called myfield):

```
<style>
#myfield {
    display: none;
}
</style>    


<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" />

<input type='text' id='myfield' name='myfield' />


<script>
if ($("#mycheckbox").is(":checked")) {
document.getElementById("id").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

However, this only works when the page loads and the checkbox is already checked. It doesn't work live when the box isn't checked on page load, and you go to click the box. I want the hidden field to show up right away when the box is "checked" without the page having to reload. I then want myfield to hide right away when the box is unchecked.

Can any anyone point out the better/proper way to do this?

Additionally:

Of note: I do know how to do this in CSS using labels, but I need to use javascript other times.

Here's what works fine in modern browsers using just CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/3KTC3/

Here's that CSS only jsfiddle code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.label-for-check {
    display:none;
}

.check-with-label:checked + .label-for-check {
display:block;  
}
</style>   


<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="check-with-label" />
  <label for="check" class="label-for-check">

        <br /><br />MyField<br />
    <input type='text' id='myfield' name='myfield' size='10'  />
</label>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach a [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler. Your posted code only executes when page is loaded, it doesn't watch over your element's state.

Here's a jQuery equivalent to your CSS version with classes and adjacent selector:

```
$('.check-with-label').change(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qV2hT/13/)

Explanation: `this` references the checkbox being clicked, get the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element (equivalent to your CSS `+` selector) and [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) its display based on the checked state of the checkbox.

Another version that works only with your 2 given IDs:

```
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
    $('#myfield').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qV2hT/17/)

Note that your CSS version is compatible with all desktop browsers including IE7 and above. Consider whether it is necessary to use JS for this.

**edit:** You have to trigger the change handler after attaching it, so if the checkbox is already checked when the page is loaded, the triggered handler will display the field.

Comment: Mine is the only correct answer. Mind commenting anonymous downvoter?

Comment: You are binding to `.check-with-label` there is no such element in the initial code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. However, when I add the "checked" attribute and load the page, It comes in a checked, but doesn't show "myfield" until you uncheck it and then re-check it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. However, when I add the "checked" attribute and load the page, It comes in a checked, but doesn't show "myfield" until you uncheck it and then re-check it.

(not that you're wrong exactly based on what I asked... just that it's functionality I didn't want to loose... the part where it works on page load)

Comment: @Chain trigger the event on page load http://jsfiddle.net/qV2hT/10/ I'll update it on the answer

Comment: @Chain I misunderstood that point the first time I've read your question, my bad. Updated answer and fiddle now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks: this helps me understand how to replicate the functionality in JS. Thank you for the quick fiddle examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#mycheckbox").is(":checked")) $('#myfield').show();

    $('#mycheckbox').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#myfield').show();
        } else {
            $('#myfield').hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that **jQuery will only check one time (when you load the site) if your checkbox is checked.**

The change handler will fire every time the user changes the checkbox, if it is cheked it will show `#myfield`

Do something like this:

```
$('#mycheckbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#myfield').show()
    }
});
```